# Why is Java returning an error rather than an IOException when try and get a file lock

Tags: java, nio, ioexception

This code running with Java 1.8.0_72 25.72-b15 64bit on Windows 8.1

```
protected FileLock getFileLockForWriting(FileChannel fileChannel, String filePath) throws IOException
    {
        logger.finest("locking fileChannel for " + filePath);
        FileLock fileLock;
        try
        {
            fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();
        }
        //Assumes locking is not supported on this platform so just returns null
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Couldnt getFields lock because file is already locked by another application
        if (fileLock == null)
        {
            throw new IOException(ErrorMessage.GENERAL_WRITE_FAILED_FILE_LOCKED.getMsg(filePath));
        }
        return fileLock;
    }
```

is reporting this error for a particular user

```
java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation
    at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.newSharedFileLockTable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.fileLockTable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.AbstractID3v2Tag.getFileLockForWriting(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:1080)
    at org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.AbstractID3v2Tag.writeBufferToFile(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:1462)
    at org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag.write(ID3v23Tag.java:751)
    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.save(MP3File.java:1011)
    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.save(MP3File.java:920)
    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.commit(MP3File.java:932)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.realSave(SongSaver.java:798)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveSongToFile(SongSaver.java:623)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveChanges(SongSaver.java:185)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:160)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation
    at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.init(Native Method)
    ... 21 more
```

It seems it is returning an Error because file locking is not supported, but it should be returning an IOException, (my code expects an IOException), why should this be

**Update**
I case relevent it’s a Western Digital MyBook Live 3TBNAS, Firmware version is 02.43.10-048 which running Debian 5.0.4

Comment: I guess it is due to Access Permissions. Which OS?

Comment: According to the stack trance, which line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: Check the actual file path that you are trying to get a lock on to. It may be a path that is protected such as "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)". And your user may not have appropriate permissions regardless. Also, check that your application releases any locks after exceptions have occurred.

Comment: Well I read it that  at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.create() is throwing an Error due to an IOException thrown by sun.nio.ch.FileKey.init(). Imm running on Windows but the file is a remote drive on a NAS and Im waiting for more information about the NAS. I dont see why lack of permissions should cause such an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code above `FileKey.create` can throw a `IOException` so your assumption that this behaviour is not ok is correct.

Indeed this was already filed as [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025619). In Java 9 the `Error` will be gone and a `IOException` will be [thrown](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/655c81c02331#l6.7) instead.

Therefore for now you should be prepared to catch the error and evaluate the inner IOException.

Comment: Thanks, what Im not clear on if if this error has only be introduced since 7 u40